# Format difference in CSS selectors and how to copy them in chrome?

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, xpath

So I have this URL: [https://www.amazon.com/BEAKEY-Foundation-Blending-Flawless-Multi-colored/dp/B01F36JEXE/ref=sr_1_22?dchild=1&keywords=cosmetics&qid=1625014752&sr=8-22](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01F36JEXE)

and I noticed someone was using CSS selector from the url as

```
ul.detail-bullet-list span.a-list-item span.a-text-bold
```

however, when I right click and copy selector of an element in that url, my formatting is more like:

```
#detailBullets_feature_div > ul > li:nth-child(1) > span
```

I was wondering how I can copy selector in a format like the first one? Is that possible or is that some kind of format that you would do manually?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just copy such selector from dev tools.
The automatically generated selectors are regularly in the format you mentioned in the second locator or even worse.
So, to get a correct, stable and reliable locator you have to learn doing that your self, manually.